# Java EE 6 how can I change the default location of my web.xml file?

Tags: java-ee-6, web.xml

I was to use a custom directory structure for my Java EE 6 application. How do I make this change while keeping my project functional?

Comment: Why would you want to? What are you trying to do? Perhaps there's an actual *good* way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override this location, it's "hard-coded" in the specification. [The Servlet specification 3.0](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) says:

> ### 10.5 Directory Structure
>
> The contents of the `WEB-INF` directory are:
>
> - The `/WEB-INF/web.xml` deployment descriptor.

And nothing more about alternative locations.